# Specify Start Position for Apache Commons Kalman Filter 2D Positioning Estmation

Tags: java, android, kalman-filter, indoor-positioning-system, apache-commons-math

I use the kalmanfilter implementation of the apache commons math library to improve the accuracy of my indoor positioning framework. I think I got the matrices setup correctly for 2D positioning while the state consists of the position(x,y) and velocity(vx, vy). I set the state "x" with the new incoming position in the "estimatePosition()" method. The filter seems to work: Here is the output from my little JUnit test which calls the method estimatePosition() in a loop with the mocked position [20,20]:

- 1st recursion: Position: {20; 20} 
  Estimate: {0,0054987503; 0,0054987503}
- ...
- 100th recursion: Position: {20; 20} 
  Estimate: {20,054973733;20,054973733}

I wonder why the initial Position seems to be at [0,0]. Where do I have to set the initial Position of [20,20]?

```
public class Kalman {

    //A - state transition matrix
    private RealMatrix A;
    //B - control input matrix
    private RealMatrix B;
    //H - measurement matrix
    private RealMatrix H;
    //Q - process noise covariance matrix (error in the process)
    private RealMatrix Q;
    //R - measurement noise covariance matrix (error in the measurement)
    private RealMatrix R;
    //x state
    private RealVector x;

    // discrete time interval (100ms) between to steps
    private final double dt = 0.1d;
    // position measurement noise (1 meter)
    private final double measurementNoise = 1d;

    // constant control input, increase velocity by 0.1 m/s per cycle
    private RealVector u = new ArrayRealVector(new double[] { 0.1d });
    //private RealVector u = new ArrayRealVector(new double[] { 10d });
    private KalmanFilter filter;

    public Kalman(){
        //A and B describe the physic model of the user moving specified as matrices
        A = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(new double[][] {
                                                        { 1d, 0d, dt, 0d },
                                                        { 0d, 1d, 0d, dt },
                                                        { 0d, 0d, 1d, 0d },
                                                        { 0d, 0d, 0d, 1d }
                                                    });
        B = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(new double[][] {
                                                        { Math.pow(dt, 2d) / 2d },
                                                        { Math.pow(dt, 2d) / 2d },
                                                        { dt},
                                                        { dt }
                                                    });
        //only observe first 2 values - the position coordinates
        H = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(new double[][] {
                                                        { 1d, 0d, 0d, 0d },
                                                        { 0d, 1d, 0d, 0d },
                                                    });
        Q = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(new double[][] {
                                                        { Math.pow(dt, 4d)/4d, 0d, Math.pow(dt, 3d)/2d, 0d },
                                                        { 0d, Math.pow(dt, 4d)/4d, 0d, Math.pow(dt, 3d)/2d },
                                                        { Math.pow(dt, 3d)/2d, 0d, Math.pow(dt, 2d), 0d },
                                                        { 0d, Math.pow(dt, 3d)/2d, 0d, Math.pow(dt, 2d) }
                                                    });

        R = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(new double[][] {
                { Math.pow(measurementNoise, 2d), 0d },
                { 0d, Math.pow(measurementNoise, 2d) }
        });

        ProcessModel pm = new DefaultProcessModel(A, B, Q, x, null);
        MeasurementModel mm = new DefaultMeasurementModel(H, R);
        filter = new KalmanFilter(pm, mm);
    }


    /**
     * Use Kalmanfilter to decrease measurement errors
     * @param position
     * @return
     */
    public Position<Euclidean2D> esimatePosition(Position<Euclidean2D> position){

        double[] pos = position.toArray();
        // x = [ 0 0 0 0] state consists of position and velocity[pX, pY, vX, vY]
        x = new ArrayRealVector(new double[] { pos[0], pos[1], 0, 0 });

        // predict the state estimate one time-step ahead
        filter.predict(u);

        // x = A * x + B * u (state prediction)
        x = A.operate(x).add(B.operate(u));

        // z = H * x  (measurement prediction)
        RealVector z = H.operate(x);

        // correct the state estimate with the latest measurement
        filter.correct(z);

        //get the corrected state - the position
        double pX = filter.getStateEstimation()[0];
        double pY = filter.getStateEstimation()[1];

        return new Position2D(pX, pY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technical answer to your question is probably to set `x` to the initial state in your `Kalman()` constructor.

Practically speaking, when you initialize a Kalman filter, you will not always have an initial state that you know.  In your own case, you happen to know that the initial position is `20,20`, but what should you put in your initial velocity estimate?

One common starting point is to initialize to `0` (or whatever a reasonable mean value is) and set initial `P` to be "wide open".  I don't see how `P` is initialized in your code.  You would set it to say that your initial position is `0,0` with very large uncertainty.  That would cause initial measurements to make large adjustments to `x` as `P` converges to the steady state after many measurements.

Comment: You are right @Ben...once again. I forgot to set x before initializing the Kalman Filter! Then the start position is [20,20] as expected. Furthermore I initialize the velocity with 0. With the Apache Math Implementation I don't have to initialize P as they seem to provide some kind of default matrice.